# Rails 3: Generate foreign key contraints in structure dump from relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-schema

I want to dump my database schema to a structure.sql file but WITH the associations (has_many/belongs_to) declared in the models so I have them in on the database layer as foreign key contraints. Is  this possible?

Comment: Did you try following comment `rake db:structure:dump` ?

Comment: take a look at the foreigner gem  https://github.com/matthuhiggins/foreigner

Comment: Yup but that only creates a structure.sql file without the foreign key contraints. That being said, there are no foreign keys declared in the models, only the standard associations.

Comment: in that case also look at immigrant https://github.com/jenseng/immigrant

Comment: Thanks that's exactly what I've been looking for!